# MongoDb for collection of production data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, plc, real-time-data

I am facing a new type of problem that I haven't tried tackling before. So I would like some pointers in the right direction by someone more knowledgeable than I :-)

I have been asked by a friend to help him design a control system for production line. The project sounds really interesting, and I can't stop thinking about it.

I have already found that I can control the system using a node.js server. So far so good (HTML5 interface here we come)! But where I really want this system to stand out is in the collection of system metrics. The system reports all kinds of things such as temperature, flow etc, and these metrics are reported up to several hundred times per second per metric... and this runs 24/7.

My thought is to persist this in a MongoDb database, and do some realtime statistics on this. The "competition", if you will, seems to save this in a SQL server database and allow the operators to export aggregated data to Excel, and do statistics in Excel.

What are the strategies for doing real time statistics using a MongoDb?

I would really like to provide instant feedback and monitoring based on these metrics. Such as average temperature over the last 24 hours, spikes etc, and also enable alerts. There will not be much advanced statistics done on the server. If that is needed, I would enable export of data to a program such as SPSS.

Is MongoDb a good fit for that? I would love to use a Linux machine instead of a Windows machine with SQL Server and a WinForms Control Interface. The license fees alone are enough to put me off, although I know it probably isn't the case for the people buying the machinery.

This will not be placed in the cloud, but rather on a single server on the network. Next to the machine being operated, I will place a touch interface that through a browser will contact the node.js server to invoke PLC commands. There can be multiple machines that need controlling, and they would all be controlled by the same central node.js server.

The machinery is controlled by PLC controllers from http://beckhoff.com/.

I am not a complete novice when it comes to MongoDb, but I have never put anything I have made into production, and I wouldn't put MongoDb on my CV... yet!

EDIT: It seems that the $inc operator is the way to go. But what if I wan't both the daily and hourly averages as well as a continuous feed that updates a chart on screen with data every second using socket.io. Is is a good idea to update a document for each of the aggregates I need. I really also want to save every measurement, but maybe I could aggregate that on a per second basis, so I don't store up to a 1000 records per second per metric?

Comment: While MongoDB is "free", for a production system I would recommend paying for a yearly subscription, not only to get support, but to help pay for the continued development of MongoDB. https://www.10gen.com/products/mongodb-subscriptions

Comment: I have already looked into that, and the price for a basic subscription package is still far less than paying for the SQL server + suitable hardware. $2,500/year doesn't scare me that much if I can get a good setup going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I am really looking for is the Aggregation Framework: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-examples/

That gives me exactly the kind of stats that I would like to see. Use this to calculate sums and averages as I write, and then also allow for ad-hoc queries should they be needed.

For a little insight on performance, read this awesome blogpost!
http://devsmash.com/blog/mongodb-ad-hoc-analytics-aggregation-framework

Also, anyone else looking to do something like this should take a look at this to see how to save the individual events. I don't need to save data longer than a week for example, so a rolling log should be more than enough for me: http://blog.mongodb.org/post/172254834/mongodb-is-fantastic-for-logging

With this I am very close to having a really sweet setup, and I am beginning to feel confident that this is a good choice over MySQL or MSSQL.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB can definitely be used for your scenario. Look at http://www.slideshare.net/pstokes2/social-analytics-with-mongodb, http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/use-cases/pre-aggregated-reports/ or
[Real-time statistics: MySQL(/Drizzle) or MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830914/real-time-statistics-mysql-drizzle-or-mongodb) for more on this topic

Comment: Awesome! Will look at that right away! Is MongoDb overkill do you think?